# Form with Bootstrap+Tabs not send all item on POST event. Only first tab work fine

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-4

I'm working with From on laravel 4.2 + Blade.

When send form with post, and capture exit with dd(Item:all) only the first five elements of the form are $Var.

After load my page for edit settings, Laravel and Blade show this code. I think it's correct.

```
<form method="POST" action="http://fqdn.com/settings" accept-charset="UTF-8" novalidate="novalidate" class="form-horizontal" id="formSettings"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="iFlxF11zF8afGfqszJyOBgmIzqVLxPrSEl8N6fFK">
<div class="tab-content">
    <!-- Tab Storage -->
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="storage">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div>&nbsp;</div>
            <!-- Option Remote -->
            <div class="form-group" id="groupRemote">
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label for="storageServer" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Remote storage server</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9 ">
                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="FQDN or Ip" name="storageServer" type="text" id="storageServer">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label for="storagePort" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Port remote storage server</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Port number" name="storagePort" type="text" id="storagePort">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label for="storageUser" class="col-sm-3 control-label">User remote storage server</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="username" name="storageUser" type="text" id="storageUser">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label for="storagePath" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Path on remote storage server</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="/remote/path" name="storagePath" type="text" id="storagePath">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Option local -->
            <div class="form-group hidden" id="groupLocal">
                <div class="form-group  ">
                    <label for="storageLocal" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Path on remote storage server</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="/local/path" name="storageLocal" type="text" id="storageLocal">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- STOP SEND PAR KEY & VALUE of rest of elements of form
    <!-- Tab Frecuency -->
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="frequency">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div>&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="form-group" id="groupFrequency">
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label for="maxDaily" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Limit copies (daily)</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="maxDaily" placeholder="Number copies">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label for="maxMonthly" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Limit copies (monthly)</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="maxMonthly" placeholder="Number copies">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label for="maxSnap" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Limit copies (snap)</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="maxSnap" placeholder="Number copies">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label for="alertSize" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Max size</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="alertSize" placeholder="85 (Maximum size of space on the server to send alert)">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 text-center">
    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Save">
</div>
```

Sort of dd(Input::all()); on SettingsController.php

```
array (size=6)
'_token' => string 'iFlxF11zF8afGfqszJyOBgmIzqVLxPrSEl8N6fFK' (length=40)
'storageServer' => string '' (length=0)
'storagePort' => string '' (length=0)
'storageUser' => string '' (length=0)
'storagePath' => string '' (length=0)
'storageLocal' => string '' (length=0)
```

I don't understand and I don't see my error on form.

Comment: give us controller code.

Comment: https://github.com/abkrim/formtab thanks

Comment: i can't find  FormController.php

Comment: Sorry.. on post change name.. correct name for MVC it's SettingsController, Settings model, and settings.blade for view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works fine if you see only 5 inputs(when radio boxes are not checked), because if checkbox and radio boxes are not checked they are not transfered as post variables. If you have:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="a" value="a" checked="checked"></input>
```

Your post variable named a will have content "a"

```
<input type="checkbox" name="a" value="b" checked="checked"></input>
```

Your post variable named a will have content "b"

```
<input type="checkbox" name="a" value="a"></input>
```

Your post variable named a will not be set(Of course if this checkbox is not checked in form).

EDITED:

You don't have name attribute in last 4 inputs, add them "name" and everything will work.

Comment: Are you sure what you say? Ok. if are your sure, you try delete checkbox for test pourposes, and the problem persist. Also, my radio it's correct. Pair of elements has same name and diferente value. Thanks for you reply.

Comment: I put a branch on git hub without-radio, with no radio buttons for demostrate that your response not valid for the problem

Comment: A lot of thanks.. One more time... work too many hours despite. 
I modify the code in blade for the answer but forget the code for the components. Indeed all components after 5 were not the attribute name.